# ViewModelProviders.get(...) in base class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to cut some of Dagger's boilerplate by moving some of my ViewModel instantiation in an abstract base class but can't find quite a good way to do this. My intent is to instantiate all my ViewModels from my base fragment for them to be ready to consume by all child fragments without having them do their own instantiation. My issue lies in retrieving the ViewModel using a generic (VM)- specifically here: `.get(viewModel::class.java)` . I also attempted `.get(VM::class.java)` that is not permitted

**BaseFragment**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<VM : ViewModel> : Fragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    lateinit var viewModel : VM

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(viewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

**ViewModelProviders.get(...) method signature**

```
public <T extends ViewModel> T get(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: check out this blog post https://mag.n26.com/reducing-viewmodel-provision-boilerplate-in-googles-githubbrowsersample-549818ee72f0

Comment: Wish I found this days ago, this is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `BaseFragment` defined like this:

```
public class BaseFragment<T extends ViewModel> extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    protected T viewModel;

}
```

You can use the [ViewModelUtils](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/ViewModelUtil.java) class from the Architecture Components's Github browser sample to create `ViewModel` factories.

```
/**
 * Creates a one off view model factory for the given view model instance.
 */
public class ViewModelUtil {
    private ViewModelUtil() {}
    public static <T extends ViewModel> ViewModelProvider.Factory createFor(T model) {
        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(model.getClass())) {
                    return (T) model;
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected model class " + modelClass);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In the `onActivityCreated` method of the `BaseFragment` you can add

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel);
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(viewModel.getClass());
    }
```

The code for this technique is from [this blog post](https://mag.n26.com/reducing-viewmodel-provision-boilerplate-in-googles-githubbrowsersample-549818ee72f0).

Comment: But this way all the fragments will have the same context as they have extend the same fragment, and the values in the viewmodel will be live forever.
Is this right?, I have this problem how to avoid this.

Comment: Looks good, but the injected ViewModels are not the same instance after orientation changes, because they are generated every time :(

Answer (score 7):

```
val viewModel: T by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(getTClass())
}

//获取泛型T的实际类型
private fun getTClass(): Class<T> {
    return (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but fix it with a bit of Reflection; I really don't like to use Reflection on Android, but didn't have other option.

```
private void initViewModel() {
    final Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get((Class<M>) types[0]);
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone.