# Getting generic class from Kotlin Generic

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following class signature:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<E : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected lateinit var viewModel: E

}
```

Now I want to initialize my viewModel in a generic way using ViewModelProvider, so:

```
   viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(MyViewModel::class)
```

Given that MyViewModel class will be provided in the generic type, I'd say this could potentially be abstracted into the BaseActivity so I dont have to do it for every Activity that extends it.

I tried with:

```
inline fun <reified E : ViewModel> getViewModelClass() = E::class.java
```

But then when doing:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(getViewModelClass())
```

I get `Cannot use E as reified type paramter. Use class instead`

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

`E` in `BaseActivity` can't be `reified`, so you can't pass it to any methods which take a `reified E`.

Your best option may just be to accept the class as a constructor parameter.

```
abstract class BaseActivity<E : ViewModel>(private val modelClass: Class<E>) : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected lateinit var viewModel: E

    ... viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        .get(modelClass)
}
```

If `BaseActivity` wasn't abstract, you could add a factory method:

```
// outside BaseActivity class itself
fun <reified E : BaseModel> BaseActivity() = BaseActivity(E::class.java)
```

but it wouldn't help when extending it.

Answer (score 1):

You ca do it in this way:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<E : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

protected lateinit var viewModel: E

abstract fun getViewModel():E

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        .get(getViewModel())
}

}
```

Now, you can extend any class from BaseActivity and override the getViewModel() function returning the respective ViewModel class.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Try this once:

```
 inline fun <reified E> getViewModelClass(): Class<E> {
    return E::class.java
}
```

and use it like this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        .get(getViewModelClass())
```

Comment: this still forces me to implement boilerplate on the subclasses. It is an improvement though

Comment: Did you get any error when you used your inline function getViewModelClass() you mention above ?

Comment: yes, `Cannot use E as reified type paramter. Use class instead`

Comment: can you try the Edit answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107111/8832537

You should check this guy's solution. The only downside of his approach is he uses Reflection API to get the generic parameter. I researched a lot but didn't find a solution that doesn't use reflection. If you did find it, let me know. That would be more convenient.